# Python デフォルト引数を利用して文字列を返すには?

Tags: python

'こんばんは〇〇くん'という文字列を返したいです。○○には引数で渡された値を入れたいです。引数に指定のない場合は'名前無し'を表示したいです。
　　デフォルト引数がよく分かっていないです。
　　その他にもエラーが出たりします。

```
def aqqui_message(name,name='名前無し'):
    print('こんばんは'+name+'くん')

aqqui_message('二郎')
aqqui_message()
```

Comment: Itagaki Fumihikoさん、ご回答ありがとうございました。Noneを使うことで引数を指定しない場合を作り出すことができるのですね。この度はありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

引数の規定値を`None`にします。
`None`はその変数が未定義であることを表します。
そして`if`文で判定して分岐させます。

```
def aqqui_message(name=None):
    if(name is None):
        print('名前無し')
    else:
        print('こんばんは'+name+'くん')
```

Comment: 質問がわかりにくくてすみません。引数を指定しない場合は、こんばんは名前無しくん　ではなく、名前なし　と表示させたいのです。

Comment: print('こんばんは'+name+'くん') これで 名前なし と表示できるわけがないですよね。これに代わるコードが欲しいということですか？

Comment: はい、引数を与えた場合はこんばんは○○くん、与えない場合は名前なし、と表示させたいのです。私が仕組みを根本的に分かっていないので、お手を煩わせてしまうと思いますが、コードの例を教えていただきますでしょうか。

Comment: 回答を編集しました。